# Minify CSS and Bootstrap files for a web site to work faster

Tags: css, minify

What program can I use to minify CSS files and bootstrap.min.js into one line? and also how can I reduce the weight of my web site to work faster? I hope some one can help me.

Comment: Have you asked a search engine on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a few lines of code, you can use an online minifier https://www.cleancss.com/css-minify/

But if you're working on a big project, I recommend you to install postcss https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-postcss-for-minification-and-optimization--cms-24568

Those are the instructions, as you may need to install node and npm to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Check minifier.org. There you can minify js and css files.